# SQL Performance Inner Join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let me ask you something I've been thinking about for a while. Imagine that you have two tables with data:

**MAIN TABLE (A)**

```
| ID         | Date        | 
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |   01-01-1990|    
| 2          |   01-01-1991|    
| 3          |   01-01-1992|   
| 4          |   01-01-2000|    
| 5          |   01-01-2001|    
| 6          |   01-01-2003|
```

**SECONDARY TABLE (B)**

```
| ID         | Date        |  TOTAL  |
|:-----------|------------:|--------:|
| 1          |   01-01-1990|   1     |  
| 2          |   01-01-1991|   2     |    
| 3          |   01-01-1992|   1     |   
| 4          |   01-01-2000|   5     |    
| 5          |   01-01-2001|   8     |    
| 6          |   01-01-2003|   7     |
```

and you want to select only ID with date **greater than 31-12-1999 and get the following columns: ID, Date and Total**. For that we have many options but my question would be which of the following would be better in terms of performance:

**OPTION 1**

```
With  main as(
select id, 
       date
from A
where date > '31-12-1999'
)

select main.id,
       main.date,
       B.total
from main inner join B on main.id = b.id
```

**OPTION 1**

```
With  main as(
select id, 
       date
from A
where date > '31-12-1999'
),

secondary as (
select id, 
       total
from B
where date > '31-12-1999'
)

select main.id,
       main.date,
       secondary.total
from main inner join secondary on main.id = b.id
```

Which of both queries would be better in terms of performance? Thanks in advance!

**DATE FOR BOTH TABLES MEANS THE SAME**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use CTE you can directly join two tables -

```
select A.id,
       A.date,
       B.total
from A inner join B on A.id = b.id
where A.date > '31-12-1999'
```

Comment: Thanks Fahmi. In that case it will throw an error because we you need to specify the table for the date filter. Hope it helps!

Comment: Would it be better to filter on the second table as well? Or is the inner join executed firstly?

Comment: join would execute first @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You would need to test on your data.  But there is really no need for CTEs:

```
select a.id a.date, b.total
from a inner join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
where a.date > '1999-12-31' and b.date > '1999-12-31';
```

As for your specific question, the two queries are not the same, because the first is filtering on only one date and the second is filtering on two dates.  You should run the query that implements the logic that you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Probably there is no need for CTEs as you said but it was just an example. My question would be: Would it be better to filter on the second table with the date even thought the inner join will get the same result? Date for boths tables mean the same

Comment: @Daniel . . . The two queries are different.  Use the one that implements the logic you need.  You either need to filter on one table or both tables . . . or you need to fix your data model so you don't have redundant data.  If the id/date values are the same in both tables, no `join` at all is needed, and that will be faster.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I didn't want to give an actual example because it would be longer to explain but imagine that you have that situation. Even the inner join will give the desired result, would it be better to use a where clause to reduce the amount of data we read or the inner join is executed firstly so it doesnt matter?